# How to organize templates in Symfony

Tags: symfony, templates, twig, web-deployment, symfony-3.3

I have an application build with `Symfony 3.3` and `Twig` that will be distributed to more customers. I'm using `parameters.yml` to customize its behavior and it seems to work well.

Where I have an issue is with `twig` templates: although the customers will use most of the templates as they are, they'll need to customize some parts like CSS styles, general layout and do occasional design overrides.

The options I have identified are:

1. Have a full set of templates for each customer. The issue is that the upgrades will be a nightmare as we have to patch each template and account for differences
2. Customize templates via YML files. The problem is that it gets too complicated soon and the number of parameters is potentially huge
3. Deliver a set of templates in `app/Resources/views` and allow the customer to override any of the templates by creating another file with the same name in another folder
4. Deliver a set of templates in `AppBundle/Resources/views` and let customers override them in `app/Resources/views`
5. Create the application as a Symfony bundle (ie. MyAppBundle) and deploy the application to each customer by including the MyAppBundle via composer. **I like this solution** a lot, but I do not know whether it is possible to implement is easily.

Do you have any suggestion on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way in your case is to think about the main parts and the customer parts and then build blocks and overwrite all parts that are relevant for the customer for example the CSS or anything else. If you know that there are special part you can build macros for example.

With the Block concept you can predefine the template but the customer has the ability to overwrite that part you've defined with it's own.

With Twig you have a lot of possibilities to solve such a problem.

Drupal 8 use that Theming concept.

https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/twig-concepts-drupal-8-themes-part-ii

Perhaps you can take a look how they have solved that and you can find a good solution for your problem.